# Text alignment in a \sortedlist environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, sorting, description, justification

I'm using the following command :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}    
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand{\sortitem}[2]{%
\DTLnewrow{list}%
\DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#1}%
\DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#2}%
}

\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
\DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}%
}{%
\DTLsort{label}{list}%
\begin{description}%
\DTLforeach*{list}{\theLabel=label,\theDesc=description}{%
\item[\theLabel] \theDesc}%
\end{description}%
}
```

Command that I use to write

```
\begin{document}
\begin{sortedlist}
\sortitem{$\underline{M}$}{Matrice des masses généralisées $[\mathrm{kg}]$}
\sortitem{$\underline{TEST}$}{Text here bigger than '' Matrice des masses généralisées''}
\end{sortedlist}
\end{document}
```

Which give me :

[image]

Now I would like to modify the sortedlist (before \begin{document}) command to justify the text at a certain distance from the edge of the page, which should give :

[image]

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can measure the labels to find the widest one and the use `enumitem` features.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}    
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\sortitem}[2]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#1}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#2}%
}

\newlength{\sortedlistwd}
\newlength{\sortedlistwdtemp}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}%
}{%
  \DTLsort{label}{list}%
  \setlength{\sortedlistwd}{0pt}%
  \DTLforeach*{list}{\theLabel=label}{%
    \settowidth{\sortedlistwdtemp}{\theLabel}%
    \ifdim\sortedlistwdtemp>\sortedlistwd
      \setlength{\sortedlistwd}{\sortedlistwdtemp}%
    \fi
  }%
  \begin{description}[labelwidth=\sortedlistwd]
  \DTLforeach*{list}{\theLabel=label,\theDesc=description}{%
    \item[\theLabel] \theDesc}
  \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{sortedlist}
\sortitem{$\underline{M}$}{Matrice des masses généralisées $(\mathrm{kg})$}
\sortitem{$\underline{TEST}$}{Text here bigger than ``Matrice des masses généralisées''}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

I fixed a couple of errors in the input (units should be in parentheses, not in brackets and opening quotes should be typed in as

```
``
```

(two back-quotes) not as `''`.

[image]